# Linkedin Connection API failed

Tags: linkedin-api

I use the [REST console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) to run LinkedIn APIs to collect connections' public profile URL.

For example, in Service, I select "Get My connections", Authentication "OAuth 2"   If I try the following request it is OK:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&count=4000&modified=updated
```

Since I have more than 20K connections, I have to limit the count to a number less than 5000. Before, I could run multiple queries to collect the data by changing the `start` and `count` parameters. For instance:

```
start=0&count=4000
start=4001&count=4000
start=8001&count=4000
```

etc.

However, now, if I put a non-zero number in 'start' parameter, it always returns an internal error (below). How can I resolve this?

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem requesting 500 contacts at a time:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&count=500&modified=updated
```

And last week that started giving me the same `500 Internal Server Error`.

I reduced the count to 100 and it started working again.  250 works too.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&count=100&modified=updated
```